# Multiple Activity Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar, progress

I have 4 activities: changeView, changeViewTwo, NoRunning, YesRunning.
Also, I have 2 XML: yes_running and no_running

The first screen (no_running), has a button that changes the view like this:

```
Button buttonchange01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    buttonchange01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new     Intent("com.example.runningtimer.changeView"));
        }
    });
```

on the manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="changeView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.runningtimer.changeView" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

on the changeView.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yes_running);
}
```

that is done correctly, however, when the new one is on view, I have a progressbar that counts to 10 and it should go back to no_running.xml but it doesnt, this is how YesRunning activity looks like

```
public class YesRunningActivity extends Activity {

ProgressBar myProgressBar;
int myProgress = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yes_running);
    myProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
    new Thread(myThread).start();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.no_running, menu);
    return true;
}
public Runnable myThread = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (myProgress<100){
            try{
                myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(Throwable t){ }
        }
        if (myProgress==100){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.runningtimer.changeViewTwo"));
            myProgress = 0;
        }
    }

    Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myProgress++;
            myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
        }
    };
};
}
```

manifest for changeViewTwo

```
<activity
        android:name="changeViewTwo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.runningtimer.changeViewTwo" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

changeViewTwo

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.no_running);
}
```

Any idea why it is not going back? or how can I make it go back?

Comment: what problem u are getting with current code

Comment: Once it goes to yes_running.xml , it does not goes back to no_running.xml after 10 seconds

Comment: followed this page and it worked, changed view for activity
http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/